# Что означает @ в css?

Tags: css

Впервые такое вижу. Найти ничего не смог. Увидел это в twitter bootstrap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Ответ 1](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/atrules/), [ответ 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-syntax/#at-rules) (официальный). Как вы искали?? Гуглится за пять секунд.